# Packaging SDL2 when compiling on Ubuntu

Tags: compilation, ubuntu-14.04, sdl-2

I have created a game for my Uni project, said game runs fine however I can't run it on the University computers that don't have SDL2 installed and getting SDL2 installed on them is not possible.

Is there a way to package the SDL2 files while compiling so that I can run it on any Ubuntu system?

Comment: This question gets asked far too often. Check 'related' questions. Short version is you either link with static version (which you're unlikely to have, so you'll need to build one), or bring required libraries with your program and use script with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./your_program` or define rpath at linking phase.

Comment: [something something `RPATH`](http://freegamedev.net/wiki/Portable_binaries)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If this question is asked a lot I couldn't find where it was asked for the life of me. I'll try what you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are right. You should use the Linux tool 'chrpath' or the rpath flag with gcc in order to reference your own packaged SDL libraries in your game binary.

As a starting point, I advise you to take a look at the Makefile of the GPL game [Rock Dodger CE](https://bitbucket.org/josephpaul0/rockdodger-ce) on bitbucket. It does what you are looking for. It references SDL2 libraries with the -rpath compiler flag.

In addition, that game ships the SDL2 libraries for 3 Linux  architectures (i686, Amd64, ARMv7l).
(*Look at the download section for the 'multiarch' package for Linux.*) You can use those compiled libraries if they fit your requirements and you don't want to rebuild everything yourself.

I agree with you on the fact that there is not (yet) a comprehensive documentation about how to create "*universal*" packages for SDL2 games on Linux. Or I haven't found it yet ;)

Building compatible binaries for many Linux distributions requires first to understand the '[Linux Standard Base 5.0](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/)'. The tool *Linux App Checker* (from LSB) is designed to help you to achieve maximum portability for your binaries.

From my experience, I think that CentOS 5 is by far the most appropriate 'Long Term Support' Linux distribution for building universal binaries.